# Displaying multiple values with Telerik ASP.Net MVC extensions with the ForeignKey column

Tags: html-helper, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

From what I've read, it doesn't seem possible to associate a ForeignKey column as a multi-select listbox. Is this true?

If it's not true, I am famiiar with using the ForeginKey column and would like to know how to accomplish this with a code snippet, if possible.

If it's true that it's not supported (I have the latest extensions of the tools), how would I go about to implement this? If Telerik doesn't have a work around, what I'd like to to is below.

The next best thing would be to **display the users in multiple rows (each distinct value selected for the specified group)**, I guess. **How would I implement this scenario using the ForeignKey or otherwise?** Meaning, **there can be many users for many groups**. A picture is worth a thousand words. Please see below what I'd like to implement.

fyi, I have the value and text info for both columns, but **the Groups column is not a listbox; it's a textbox** and has the text value displayed. **The Users ListBox would have the value selected for each user (assume that the users listbox contains a list of 10 users).**

```
Grid abc
Groups column (contains text value)    Users column (this is a ForeignKey ListBox)
-----------------------------------    -----------------------------------------------------------
grp1                                                        user1
grp1                                                        user2
grp1                                                        user3      
grp2                                                        user2
grp2                                                        user3
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I suggest you to create hierarchy of Grid to edit such relation.

e.g.

```
grp1
   user1
   user2
   user3
grp2
   user2
   user3
```

Implementation about hierarchy with editing can be found [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/code-library/aspnet-mvc/grid/enable-crud-in-ajax-bound-grid-with-hierarchical-master-details-views.aspx).

Option 2 -> Since the Extensions does not have a multi select it would not be so easy to add such editor template. Anyway if you implement the multi-select somehow by hand you can use add it as editor as shown [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/clientedittemplates).

Regarding ForeignKey - it is not an option.